# WOO Theme Missing Blog Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woothemes

I am working on this site for a client http://draristotle.com/ but just noticed the blog page isn't working. It was working a few days ago. I don't have too much experience with WOO themes, but I checked to see if it's a specific page that specifies where the posts go, if it was set up through WP settings but can't find it.

Is it a function? How do I find the blog page? Any ideas / fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you have to create a blank page (you can call it "Blog") and from the right there is a drop-down box titled "Template". From that drop-down box you should be able to see a blog template option.

Just remember to add the new page to your menu if you cant see it in the front end.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what it was. Thanks! :)